# Android permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in Android 11

Tags: android, permissions

What is the difference between `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`?

My application needs to apply for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to read recordings. Recently I was told that I need to meet Google’s policy requirements about the All files access permission.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9956427?hl=en#zippy=%2Cpermitted-uses-of-the-all-files-access-permission%2Cexceptions

Comment: You do not have to apply for WRITE if you wanna read. Something else comes in mind.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I also need the permission to WRITE. If my app applies for this MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, does it mean that it has both read and write permissions?

Comment: You first obtain read and or write permission. After that the manage.